# Zend\Form\Form not displayin error message from custom validator

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-validate

I'v creatated a custom validator:

```
class MyValidator extends AbstractValidator
{
    const ERROR_CONST = 'error';

    protected $dbAdapter;
    protected $messageTemplates = array(
        self::ERROR_CONST => "Error msg for '%value%'."
    );

    public function __construct($dbAdapter)
    {
        $this->dbAdapter = $dbAdapter;
    }

    public function isValid($value, $context = null)
    {
        $this->setValue($value);
        /**
         * Do validation against db
         */

        if(/* Not valid */){
            $this->error(self::ERROR_CONST);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The validation work, I've been able to test it. What doesn't work is the output of the error message using

```
echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('action'));
```

All that is outputted is an empty UL. Is this a translator issue? When I do a get_class on $this->getTranslator() in the validator I get the validator class name. When I var_dump $this->getTranslator() it outputs null. Do I need to set a translator for this to work and where would be the best place to set that translator so that it's system wide for my own validators?

Comment: Could you put some code how you use it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you define a `__construct` method for your validator class, the parent `__construct` is not implicitly called:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php (see the note)

You should modify your `__construct` method:

```
public function __construct($dbAdapter)
{
    $this->dbAdapter = $dbAdapter;
    //parent::__construct($options);
    parent::__construct(null); // or (void)
}
```

As you can see, `$messageTemplates` and `$messageVariables`  are "loaded" from `AbstractValidator::__construct`, for being used in some methods ( `error` included):

https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Validator/AbstractValidator.php#L73-L79

Comment: As simple as that. Sometimes you just need someone to point out the obvious. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to add **messageVariables** ?

```
/**
 * Message variables
 * @var array
 */
protected $messageVariables = array(
    'value'  => 'value',
);
```

Comment: I don't use any variables except the value parameter. According to the docs it isn't needed to specify a messageVariables variable. But just to try it I want ahead an added it anyway, but still no luck.